# Three js, get the vector3 that pointerlockcontrolsi s facing

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

Wondering if it's possible to get the way the yaw object in pointer lock controls is facing and use that as a direction for a raycaster. I've been toying around with the code, trying to add some basic shooter stuff to it. I've been trying a few things i've found on stack overflow with the X & Y values from the yaw object the pointer controls provides, but no luck. Here's what I have so far:

```
setupTarget: function() {
  //var vector = new THREE.Vector3(game.mouse.x, game.mouse.y, 0);
  var yaw = game.controls.getObject();
  var pitch = game.controls.pitchObject;
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
    yaw.position.x * Math.cos(pitch.rotation.x),
    yaw.position.y * Math.sin(yaw.rotation.y),
    0
  );
  var dir = vector.sub(yaw.position).normalize();
  this.ray = new THREE.Raycaster(yaw.position.clone(), dir);
}
```

I know that's wrong aside from it's not working. Was confusing some math for calculating x & y translation based on rotation, but that doesnt work for the target obviously.

Comment: I think you can just do `new THREE.Raycaster(this.position, this.rotation)` to get a ray pointing in the direction an object is looking.

Comment: I did give that a shot, but no luck on it working :(

Comment: Is your question "How do I get the direction the camera is looking when using `PointerLockControls`?".

Comment: OK. Change your question and title, and I'll give you the answer. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your copy of `PointerLockControls` ( or wait a few days for the next release):

```
this.getDirection = function() {

    // assumes the camera itself is not rotated

    var direction = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 );
    var rotation = new THREE.Euler( 0, 0, 0, "YXZ" );

    return function( v ) {

        rotation.set( pitchObject.rotation.x, yawObject.rotation.y, 0 );

        v.copy( direction ).applyEuler( rotation );

        return v;

    }

}();
```

three.js r.59

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Instead of passing the vector in, I set v to: `var v = yawObject.position.clone();`

Comment: Do not use `clone()` or `new` in a tight loop -- reuse `v`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with the new Version it do not work. I have to add

```
var v = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 );
```

before

```
v.copy( direction ).applyEuler( rotation );
```

because Firefox do not recognize v.

Comment: The function as implemented in three.js r.62 should work correctly in Firefox and any other browser. If you are having problems, you need to make a new post.

Comment: I ended up doing it a little bit differently (against west's solid advice) https://github.com/agmcleod/7dfps2013/blob/master/js/pointer_lock_controls.js#L119. Generally though what you want to do is pass the vector object to the getDirection function call.